# TinyMCE Editor removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using version 4.1.5 of TnyMCE Editor and when i do assign the HTML content with white space as below

```
<h1>Hello this is text with                    whiteSpace</h1>
```

its removing the white space in TinyMce Editor. How we can keep the white space in Tiny MCE Editor?

[image]

Regards
Vik

Comment: It's not TinyMCE that does this, but HTML itself as duplicated whitespace is ignored. If you want the whitespace to be retained use non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function which can convert your string to an HTML compatible version.

```
function encodeWhiteSpaces(str) {
   return s.split('').map(function(c) {
    if (c === ' ') 
        return '&nbsp;'
    else
        return c;
   }).join('');
}
```

The string is converted to an array(`split`), then created a new arrray (`map`) with all white spaces converted to `&nbsp;`, finally join the array back to a string (`join`).

---

Also you can use string `replace` method to convert all the white spaces to `&nbsp;`

```
s.replace(" ","&nbsp;");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as Rory already stated. Browsers ignore several spaces.
In order to solve this issue you will have to insert/encode your spaces with non-breaking spaces between the regular spaces.

**Example**:

```
"      " // six spaces
" &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" // needed encoding
```